# Fsck Expect Script

Tags: loops, scripting, expect, mount, fsck

So as the title suggests I am trying to create an expect script that will run ***fsck*** on my corrupted drive. The goal is to repair the drive so I can mount it and recover the data from it.

When running the command manually I get:

> Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
>   Abort y?

If I state ***"NO"*** it will begin the check, and I receive:

> /dev/footage/TrickCeratops contains a file system with errors, check forced.
>   Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks and sizes
>   Error reading block 1221066784 (Invalid argument) while getting next inode from scan. Ignore error y?

I can then state ***"YES"*** to move forward and it will prompt me again with:

> Force rewrite y ?

This is where I'm running into the problem... I can automate up to the first two answers, but am unable to get my expect script to answer ***"YES"*** on the ***"Force rewrite?"*** If I can get it to answer the 2nd and 3rd questions yes, I would then need to loop it until completion.

So far my script looks as such:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    expect -c'

       set timeout -1

       set temp password

       spawn ./e2fsckscript.sh

       expect "password for user:"

       send "$temp\r"

       expect "Abort<y>?"

       send "no\r"

       expect {

               "Ignore error<y>?"{
                    send "yes\r"
               }

               "Force rewrite<y>?"{
                    send "yes\r"
               }
               exp_continue
       }
    '
```

The ***"spawn ./e2fsckscript.sh"*** simply runs a command:

> sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/footage/TrickCeratops

Comment: Why don't you run `e2fsck -y ...other stuff...`?

Comment: because if i run e2fsck -y it will answer yes to the abort prompt and exit

Comment: @pynexj I'm fairly new to linux and scripting in general, so maybe you can help me a bit more. I'm not really seeing how sexpect will affect what I'm trying to do? Seems exactly the same as what I'm already doing?

Comment: just because i noticed you are using `expect -c ...` in a bash script which indicate to me you are more confortable with bash scripts.